# VHDL: is it correct to compare an unsigned with an integer?

Tags: vhdl

Is it correct (i.e. a standard thing to do, universally recognized correctly by all tools) to compare (or use) an unsigned (from ieee.numeric_std) and an integer?

examples are

```vhdl
--- example 1
if unsigned(a_vector) = 6 then

--- example 2
a_vector <= unsigned(a_vector) + 6
```

Thank you

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.3 Integer types "Integer literals are the literals of an anonymous predefined type that is called *universal_integer* in this standard. Other integer types have no literals. However, for each integer type there exists an implicit conversion that converts a value of type *universal_integer* into the corresponding value (if any) of the integer type (see 9.3.6).".

Comment: Overloads for the two operators are provided by functions in package numeric_std (-2008): `function "=" (L : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED; R : NATURAL) return BOOLEAN;` and `function "+" (L : UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED; R : NATURAL) return UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED;`. NATURAL is a subtype of INTEGER. The literal 6 is a value of type UNIVERSAL_INTEGER  and is implicitly converted to type INTEGER. 16.3 Package STANDARD `subtype NATURAL is INTEGER range 0 to INTEGER'HIGH;` The implicit conversions here meet the constraint of subtype NATURAL.

Comment: In -2008 type UNSIGNED is a resolved subtype of type UNRESOLVED_UNSIGNED. In the -1996 release of  numeric_std (IEEE Std 1076.3-1997) the type in the function declarations would be type UNSIGNED. -2008 changed the way resolution is associated with sub types. Package numeric_std is included in IEEE Std 1076-2008. In all revisions the implementer is not allowed to removed functionality from the package. Tools conforming to IEEE Std 1076-1987 are not guaranteed to support package numeric_std. All vendor implementations conforming to -1993 or newer support package numeric_std.

Comment: A better question might be : does numeric_std define operators that do such a comparison? It does, and they work fine, and synthesise fine. So go ahead. Better : if `a_vector` represents an unsigned number, declare it as `unsigned` in the first place and lose the type conversion ugliness.